# C# WebBrowser not showing Images

Tags: c#, image, browser

My WebBrowser Control in C# acts strange, sometimes it doesn't show any Pictures..

But I can see in Fiddler or in Proxy Server that it's loading them!

For example Stackoverflow Site:

[image: Stackoverflow Site]

As you can see the Stackoverflow Logo isn't there, at the side from android tag the picture is missing, and the User Avatars are missing..

But as I open the Site in IE, everything is fine.

My Registry Keys for the Browser-Emulation are on 9000 (also tried 9999)..

Of course I also cleared cache from Internet Explorer..

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you using proxy? it could be filted by proxy

Comment: What version of VS do you use?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and it's .NET Framework 4.0 and I tried with or without Proxy.

Comment: Hard to guess, but it is one of the bits you can configure in Control Panel + Internet Options, Advanced tab, Multimedia group.

Comment: The thing is, in Internet Explorer, everything is fine.